# Caps Lock, Volume control and Brightness Onscreen Display Missing in lenovo Think Center

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, display-settings, display-driver

I have done a fresh install of 64 bit Window 7 from a previous 32 bit. I have almost everything back, but some settings are not back. There used to be a display feature for example when I use to hit the caps lock button I used to have an immediate display that used to guide me whether the caps lock is on or off. See the below Image →

[image]

But I am missing it now I have wasted around 5 hours, and could not get this feature back. I have installed all the display driver and hot keys, but I guess I missing the actual driver/utility/hot key that will help me to get this feature back. I am feeling paralyzed w/o this feature.

There is a troubleshooting step mentioned here →
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkVantage-Technologies/How-to-access-Hotkey-settings/ta-p/511845

When i follow the above steps I do not see this part after clicking on advanced settings →https://www.screencast.com/t/sPrXcfYW

It looks like some driver/utility is missing. Any think center machine user can guide me who has faced the same issue in past.

Similar features also missing for

1. Brightness
2. Volume Control
3. Num Lock
4. Volume Mute

System details →

**Operating System**

Windows 7 Home Basic (x64) Service Pack 1 (build 7601)

Install Language: English (United States)

System Locale: English (United States)

Installed: 2/17/2017 6:02:31 AM

**LENOVO 3574G5Q ThinkCentre Edge 72z**

**Processor**

3.30 gigahertz Intel Core i3-2120

128 kilobyte primary memory cache

512 kilobyte secondary memory cache

3072 kilobyte tertiary memory cache

64-bit ready

Multi-core (2 total)

Hyper-threaded (4 total)

Although my system is still under warranty. The Lenovo support is very poor I am afraid if they will help me. They have mastered the art of saying "**NO**" → Their attitude is just get rid of the customer.

Comment: These are usually referred to as hotkey integration drivers. I'll look around and see what I can find

Comment: If you go into device manager, does it show that any drivers are missing?

Comment: Hey there, Please see this → https://s3.amazonaws.com/projectsts/Think+Centre/device-manager.png  Did you happened to find anything?

Comment: I could have swore I saw another comment saying you installed something and the functionality returned? It was something about a USB keyboard driver I believe?

Comment: I have 102 degree fever today. will update the whole solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your system cannot download some drivers that lenovo requires.

To solve it you can download [System Update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/mx/es/downloads/ds012808) on your pc; it's a software developed by lenovo itself. Click [HERE](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/mx/es/downloads/ds012808) to get it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to services and find "Lenovo Hotkey Client Loader"
right click on it and click on start the service